# How the updates of some apps in the Play Store start from ~50%?

Tags: google-play-store, updates

For example, when I updated Whatsapp today, the download started from 13.1MB and the app size was 23.4MB. I had disabled all auto updates. I have also noticed this in some other app updates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google Play provides delta updates, which allow you to only download the data needed to patch your existing files to the latest version.  [This is done at a binary level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19085071/how-can-improve-my-apps-incremental-updates-efficiency), so you will typically need to download more data than has changed, but still less than the entire app.